# In angular , How to use component variable in style

Tags: css, angular

I want to use a variable width in my angular 5 component template, just like this:

```
<style>
    input:checked + .slider:before {
        transform: translateX({{width}}px);
    }
</style>
```

While 'width' is a variable defined in component!

however the "{{width}}" is not parsed ,how to implement this function.thanks!

Comment: you should be having it as variable and use inline style or apply using a class

Comment: what could be width value. Can you show us calculation?

Comment: the width is a number, ex, width:number = 30;

Comment: Follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/35280715/9162349

Comment: @Ashraful Islam ,does not work at all.thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use Angular ngStyle in this case:

```
[ngStyle]="{ width: width }"
```

Take a look at this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qdqk6a)

Comment: Since OP asked for applying over CSS over pseudo element, it won't possible inline. Otherwise `ngStyle` is way to go.

Comment: @m98 thank you rapid response! in this case,the style selector is too complex ans not belong to a single element ,could you tell me how to write this in ngstyle. thanks!

Comment: @YangRui You're welcome, unfortunately you cannot have pseudoelements within inline styling

Comment: @M98,no solution for this?

Comment: No, there might be some solution, but since you're going to use `pseudo` (like `:before`), the ngStyle does not support it.  You want when the input checked, the `slider:before` use `translateX` to move. Why don't you try to do it using (let's say) Angular Animation?

Comment: @M98,i am not very familiar with css and Angular Animation. i use this just want to have a interaction,This sniper is used in a switch input,which have a dynamic width. thanks!

Comment: For Angular 7, I had to add `'` around the style, like: `[ngStyle]="{ 'stroke-width': width }" - although this was for an SVG. Maybe it applies for all styles.

Comment: how to use ngStyle for the host ? as it doesn't have an html tag