# How to bind in angular a style property of a placeholder input like text-indent of a placeholder

Tags: css, angular, binding

I know that I can do this:

```css
::-ms-input-placeholder,  /* Microsoft Edge */
:-ms-input-placeholder,   /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
::placeholder  /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
{
  text-indent: 10px;
}
```

but I want to do this with the biding property [style...]

```html
<input type="text" [style.placeholder.text-indent.px]="customIndent">
```

Comment: I honestly don't think that's possible. You'd have to target it using CSS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change style of pseudo elements in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35280118/change-style-of-pseudo-elements-in-angular2)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your problem but :

You can try this

```
    number = 10;

    getStyle() {
         style = {
           'text-indent:' : this.number + 'px'
          } 
         return style;     
    }
```

and use like :

```
<input type="text" [ngStyle]="getStyle()">
```

Comment: This is not any different from `[style.text-indent]="customIndent"` The OP's asking for styling pseudo classes.