# angular change pseudo element style by condition

Tags: html, angular, sass

I need to change :before style by condition
I try to use the https://stackoverflow.com/a/37902154/13739803 solution but not work
my code is:

```
.sender:before {
              content: "";
              width: 0px;
              height: 0px;
              position: absolute;
              border-left: 15px solid $otaghakPinkLight;
              border-right: 15px solid transparent;
              border-top: 15px solid $otaghakPinkLight;
              border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
              right: -16px;
              top: 0px;
              visibility: var(--porcentaje-visibility);
}
```

html code:

```
<div class="message-box sender" [style]="{ '--porcentaje-visibility': showAvatar ? 'visible' : 'hidden' }">test</div>
```

I want to visible or hide :before by condition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this variable needs to be placed in scss? If it can be moved into `.ts` file, I'd suggest to add conditional class in your template:

```
[class.sender--visible]="showAvatar"
```

Then you need to modify your existing `.scss` class, adding `visibility: hidden` and create a new one, which will be:

```
.sender.sender--visible::before {
    visibility: visible;
}
```