# Angular, set dynamic style to button (hover)

Tags: javascript, angular

Is it possible to assign a pseudo-class like 'hover' or 'active' to [ngStyle] ? something like: 'background-color:hover': #178102

```html
<button type="button" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': userDetails.settings.colorButtons}">
```

```js
this.userDetails.settings.colorButtons = "#179906";
```

Comment: Maybe here you can find the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35280118/change-style-of-pseudo-elements-in-angular2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change style of pseudo elements in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35280118/change-style-of-pseudo-elements-in-angular2)