# How can I change the background of a div when some field of my component is true and it is hovered?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a div and I want that when it is hovered the background color changes and I also need to choose the color based on an element in my component.

```
<div *ngFor="let u of users;" 
  [style:hover.background-color] = "u.selected ? 'red' : 'blue' ">
</div>
```

Comment: See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35280118/change-style-of-pseudo-elements-in-angular2

Answer (score 0):

From the above comment link:

"It is actually not an Angular issue: pseudo elements are not part of DOM tree, and because of that do not expose any DOM API that can be used to interact with them."

So you can instead use a CSS variable:

**Style file:**

```
.highlight:hover {
  background-color: var(--highlight-color);
}
```

**Template:**

```
    <div class="highlight" *ngFor="let u of users;" 
         [ngStyle] = "{'--highlight-color': u.selected ? 'red' : 'blue'} ">
      {{ u.name }}
    </div>
```

Comment: I need to choose the background color based on the 'selected' property of 'u'

Comment: Using the above solution, you can just extend it to work for ur case:

Comment: I added it to my sample code.